# Textarea overlaps sticky footer

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem with a textarea. It overlaps my sticky footer like shown in the image below.  How can i fix this?

[image]

css for my footer

```
#footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  border-top: 1px solid #e87f29;
  color: #efefef;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yeah i realize that this was a littel bit to much code. I'm sorry about that. I edited the post to only one of the questions with alot less code.

Comment: I'd start by adding a `z-index` property to your sticky footer and a `margin-bottom` property on your `<body>` tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need add "z-index" in the #footer css, and set the z-index number bigger than the textarea wrapper's.